# required não funciona na tag input

Tags: input

criei um form com a seguinte estrutura:

```html
<form class="container_input">
  <input class="container_input--input" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Seu Nome" required>
  <input class="container_input--input" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Seu Email" required>
  <input class="container_input--input" name="password" id="password" type="text" placeholder="Sua Senha" required>
  <input class="container_input--input" type="text" placeholder="Nível Profissional">
  <button type="submit" class="btn_register">Cadastrar</button>
  <button class="btn_return">Retornar</button>
</form>
```

porém os campos com required não estão sendo travados, eu consigo fazer o cadastro mesmo sem preencher os inputs.

Comment: A conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142062/discussion-on-question-by-chiganer-iury-required-nao-funciona-na-tag-input)